# Check if List of untrimmed Strings contain trimmed String

Tags: java, string, list, collections

We have a list of Strings which might have whitespaces at their beginning/end

We would like to check whether this list contains a string which is definitely trimmed, i.e. `listContainingUntrimmedStrings.contains(trimmedString)`

Is there a concise, preferably one-line way to do this, or we just cannot spare copying the untrimmed list into a trimmed one and perform the contains check on that / loop on the untrimmed list and do trimmed equality check on the elements one-by-one / other verbose solution?

Comment: You need to iterate over the list and for each element call the contains method. the contains method on the list will return true, only if it contains the exactly same string, but that is not what you want.

Comment: @Stultuske: Obviously it is not necessary to use exactly the contains() method from the Collection interface. We have e.g. already checked out CollectionUtils/StringUtils possibilities and also tried using streams, but found no better solution so far. The task itself is trivial, the question is whether we could do it in a more concise way (it is already down in a hierarchy of loops so we would like to avoid more of that)

Comment: @hammerfest - I am not sure if using Streams with lambda expressions will be faster than using for-loops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that in a functional style using stream operations:

```
listContainingUntrimmedStrings.stream()
    .map(String::trim)                     // lazily apply trimming to each element in the list
    .anyMatch(trimmedString::equals)       // check if any of those elements equals your initial string (assuming that `trimmedString` is NOT NULL)
```

Comment: tiny bit shorter by using `.anyMatch(trimmedString::equals)`

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what we were looking for